# How to do sumifs based on criteria included via a checkbox whose criteria value are next to the checkbox in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've started approaching it with `sumifs`, but it seems to get too troublesome, long and unmaintainable pretty soon.
`=IF(E2=true;SUMIFS(P:P;H:H;E1;L:L;$A$2;K:K;F4); IF(D2=true;SUMIFS(P:P;H:H;D1;L:L;$A$2;K:K;F4)))`

Here's the file with the data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added a possible [*solution here*](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit#gid=655454842) for you to test out:

```
=sum(ifna(filter(R:R;(xmatch(J:J;filter(B2:B10;A2:A10))*(xmatch(N:N;C2:C10))*(xmatch(M:M;filter(D2:D10;E2:E10)))))))
```

[image]